# Is there a linux filter which converts html to simple and pretty formatted text?

Tags: linux, curl

I would like to filter html response coming from cURL output. Which filter should I apply?
Viewing html content with Midnight Commander is no problem, it shows them as pretty formatted plain text, so I guess there are such a filter.

Answer (score 3):

We call these filters "Web browsers" - a program which parses HTML code and outputs pretty document.

[Links](http://www.jikos.cz/~mikulas/links/) is one of the console Web browsers which runs on Linux.

[Elinks](http://elinks.or.cz/) is another one.

Also there is [W3M](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/).

You always can copy your html code to text file and open it with GUI browser like Firefox, Chrome, Opera, etc.

Please, do not [use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1418463).

**EDIT**. I just realized you might want to prettify your HTML and see it with tags. In this case you can use [HTML tidy library project](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) or

copy your HTML to text file and surround it by `<pre>` `</pre>` tags. Then open it with your browser.

Comment: +1 for 'We call these filters "Web Browsers"' Ha!

Answer (score 1):

If you would just like to view the html output of curl in an attractive way then w3m, links or lynx as suggested above are sufficient.

If you would like to parse or do anything with the output then I recommend either the html-xml-utils linux package or [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) which is a very handy Python package for any project that involves web-scraping.

Answer (score 1):

for [lynx](https://lynx.browser.org/), the syntax is:

```
curl ... | lynx --stdin
```

(see [How to pipe html into lynx?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271945/how-to-pipe-html-into-lynx))

Answer (score 0):

midnight commander uses "links" or "lynx".
I suspect you have one of them installed if your seeing parsed HTML in the mcview.